# Why can't the console find the object I declared?

Tags: javascript

I have some problems with my code. The console can't defind the object I declared. Please help me find a solution. (Sorry for my english!)

This is for my game. I've tried to fix it but i fail.

```
...somecode

let state = {
    current : 0,
    ready : 0,
    game : 1,
    over : 2
}

...somecode
```

ps: I declare it outside curly brackets

When i type 'state' to console and press Enter. It say

```
"ReferenceError: state is not defined"
```

Comment: JavaScript should be in `<script>` tags, not `<pre>`.

Comment: my guess is pre was to format the code.... has nothing to do withit

Comment: well is the variable defined in a global scope to access it?

Comment: the console is scoped to `window`. Unless you defined `state` globally, just typing `state` in the console will do exactly what you showed happening.

Comment: My bad when write the question. I've edited it. Sorry for that

Comment: Where are you trying to access the state? Remember that if it is in a class you have to add **"this"** like ````this.state````

Comment: i declare it as a global. I type 'state' and it still error

Comment: Can we see a little more code for context? This makes no sense on its own

Comment: Can you add some more code so we can figure out what is going wrong?. just giving variable and the error is not enough to know what is wrong.

Comment: "I declare it as a global" -- show us how you do that. `let` and `const` are block-scoped, meaning if you declare a variable with them inside ANY set of curly brackets, that variable won't be accessible outside those brackets. (They won't be global, for sure.)